# An advice for a specific kind of RRDtool graph

Tags: rrdtool

I'm trying to graph some data with RRDtool and I have problems with defining the exact graph command.

The kind of graph I want is something like this:
http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/gate.spamd.week.600.png - the blue graph.

I can not "cook up" the definition for creating a graph like the one which is light blue and is on the background. It's a something between a line and an area :) . Any ideas what can I try?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is an area stacked on a transparent area or on a line ... in that way you can create a 'floating' area.

Comment: I was thinking for a similar solution, however I thought there should have a more straight-forward way for solving that.